# pytest WinError 123 on Windows 10 in conda virtual environment

Tags: windows-10, python, anaconda, virtualenv

My question is probably related to [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/1472030/pytest-oserror-winerror-123-launching-pytest-on-windows-10).
But this question did not receive any answers, so I will describe the problem again:

I open my Anaconda prompt, navigate to my project directory, and then run `pytest`.

The result differs depending on my previous settings:

1. If my standard *base* Python 3.7.3 installation is activated, everything works fine.
2. If another *myenv* conda environment is activated, I get a long list of errors. the last one being

   > OSError: [WinError 123] The syntax for filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect: 'c:\folder1\folder2\ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?